# Lifetime of temporary with assignment operator to check and align alloca()

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, assert, temporary, alloca

In the process of writing some testing and analysis of a large code base, I have to replace thousands of calls to alloca() with my own method. On my target platform alloca() fails if the number is zero, so we want to assert that is the case. We also want to provide an alignment version that is a single call. However, alloca() has specific lifetimes related to scope and so while I would like to write

```
void * CheckAndAllocate( size_t sizeInBytes )
{
  assert( sizeInBytes > 0 );
  return alloca(p); // not safe; allocation goes out of scope on return
}

void * p = CheckAndAllocate( sizeInBytes );
```

Clearly that's not an option since alloca() will not outlast CheckAndAllocate().

In the efforts of solving this, I have written this alternative using a temporary:

```
struct CheckSize
{
  inline CheckSize( size_t size ) { assert( size > 0 ); }
  inline void * operator=(void* other) { return other );
}

#define my_alloca(size) CheckSize(size) = alloca(size)

void foo(size_t size)
{
  void * p = my_alloca(size);
  // becomes
  void * p = CheckSize(size) = alloca(size);

  // ... use p locally for work
}
```

Furthermore I also defined my aligned version as:

```
struct CheckSizeAndAlign
{
  size_t _align;
  inline CheckSizeAndAlign( size_t size, size_t align ) : _align(align) { assert( size > 0 ); }
  inline void * operator=(void* other) { return AlignUp(other, _align  ); }

#define my_alloca_aligned( size, align ) CheckSizeAndAlign(size, align ) = alloca(size + align)

void foo(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
  void * p = my_alloca_aligned( size, alignment);
  // becomes
  void * p = CheckSizeAndAlign( size, alignment) = alloca( size + alignment )

  // ... use p locally for work
}
```

My question is - given that the value returned by alloca is passing through the temporary, does that violate the alloca's allocation because of any kind of scoping?

I recognize there are pitfalls around alloca, and that multiple solutions are available to fix this, but I am hoping to inject these changes into the code base without changing anything else, but simply to add some diagnostics.

I am also just curious about this specific pattern.

This is MSVC2019, CLANG and niche realtime system compilers.

Comment: Which compiler/toolset are you using?  `alloca` is not a standard function and behavior can differ among vendors.

Comment: `thousands of calls to alloca()` I am interested - _why_ was the decision made to use `alloca()` instead of dynamic allocation and smart pointers?

Comment: Re-read the question.  Can you use any modern C++ features?  Specifically, lambdas.

Comment: You could just reverse it - `alloca(CheckSize(size))` - and avoid the duplication of the size.  Then `CheckSize` can have the assert (or whatever other checking you want) and return the (possibly modified) parameter to avoid the bad `alloca(0)` call (although some libraries are fine with it).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That would work for first case, but not the alloca_aligned()

Comment: @KamilCuk not really part of the question but legacy code, realtime system, no virtual memory, etc.

Comment: @StephenNewell Anything that doesn't do heap allocations and is performant enough

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a helper function that performs your `assert`, calls `alloca`, and passes the allocated memory to a callback.  Here's my first pass at an implementation:

```
#include <alloca.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace {
    template <typename FN, typename ...ARGS>
    auto alloc_helper(std::size_t size, FN fn, ARGS && ...args) {
        assert(size > 0);
        auto p = ::alloca(size);
        return fn(p, std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto weird_add = [](void * p, auto init, auto other) {
        auto ip = reinterpret_cast<int *>(p);
        *ip = init;
        return *ip + other;
    };

    std::cout << alloc_helper(sizeof(int), weird_add, 10, 17) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This solution has the advantage of only typing the size once, plus the pointer returned by `alloca` is scoped to exactly what you want to use it; unless the callback `return`s it (you could `assert` on this, but it'd be uglier).  You can make additional helper functions to use other non-dynamic allocations (e.g., you mentioned `alloca_aligned` in a comment).

Comment: Doesn't the fact that ::alloca() happen inside alloc_helper() {} mean that the memory allocated  has a chance of going out of scope (as the stack is unwound) when it returns?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the points.  The allocated memory is scoped more tightly now.  It's only valid for the duration of the callback.

Comment: Oh I see;l so I would do all the work with the memory inside the callback? I guess I could do that but then the callback would require access to anything from the calling function required to do the work.

Comment: @Steven: Lambdas do that without a problem, and without any allocations

Comment: @MooingDuck Right I realize that. Unfortunately, it would require modifications of all the areas we use alloca right now, which I think might be a deal breaker. It is an interesting idea though.

Comment: If I misunderstood your goals, I'll delete or modify my answer.  I thought you wanted to verify the allocated size is greater than 0 (your proposal required typing size twice, mine does it once) and you were concerned about `alloca`'s result being used after being reclaimed.

Comment: @StephenNewell No I apologize if *my goals* where not clear - I want to validate the parameters and optionally align the alloca to be used in the existing scope without changing too much code. Some of these functions are quite complicated so reworking them seem impossible. As such I do not think your answer applies, though it is a useful pattern

Comment: So a simpler solution: why not just use a macro? Something like `#define CheckSize(size) alloca(size); assert(size >0)`?

Comment: @StephenNewell don't you mean to do the `assert()` before the `alloca()` rather than after?

Comment: `#define CheckSize(varname, size) assert(size > 0); auto varname = alloca(size)` ... `CheckSize(p, 10);`

Comment: I honestly didn't consider passing the variable name.  I was trying to stick with the original example the questioner had: `void * p = CheckAndAllocate( sizeInBytes );`